# Create DB2 on networked drive but managing from Windows

Tags: db2

I'm relatively new to DB world and `DB2` is very new. Below is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Install DB2 express C and IBM data studio on windows (with Fixed IP)
2. create/share/host DB2 on a shared/networked drive used within an organisation having its own fixed IP. its not a server. its `netgear NAS`.

I want this database to be shared in my organisation.

I know its relatively easy if I host it on my own windows pc (ie Localhost) but I would want to host on a network drive.

Is it possible? If so, where can I find relevant information?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request, you cannot access the data (in any reasonably way) in the database without going through the engine.

Comment: I *think* what he's asking is whether the DB2 server can be hosted on the Windows machine, but the data directory be stored on the netgear NAS (presumably accessed over SMB). I'm no expert with DB2 on Windows, but I do know that on Linux/UNIX using NFS as the data directory is a big no-no so I'd assume something similar here...

Answer (score 1):

As Lennart says, you cannot access the data without the engine. You must install the engine on an OS somewhere. Can this be a central server? Most definitely. That is how the businesses I have worked for have set up there databases, regardless of whether they were DB2 LUW, DB2 for i, or SQL Server.

So you will want to pick the OS your DB2 installs on. IMHO, I'd stay away from Windows. That pushes you to Linux or AIX. My experience was with AIX and Windows. But I have heard good things about DB2 on Linux.

Anyway....you will need to install DB2 on a central server. Data Studio is great for access and/or some management. The DB2 Express-C will be great for you to play around with most things locally before moving them to the server. Keep in mind, not every feature is available on Express-C.